# Eslint configuration for padded-blocks and lines-around-comment rule

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to use `padded-blocks` and `lines-around-comment` comment rules of eslint.

Here is my eslint configuration file.

```js
var OFF = 0, WARN = 1, ERROR = 2;
module.exports = exports = {
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "browser": false,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "modules": false
        }
    },
    "rules": {
  "padded-blocks": [WARN, "never"],
  "lines-around-comment": [WARN, { "beforeBlockComment": true}],
  
    }
};
```

If I write like this

```js
class MyClass {

 /**
  * Creates an instance of MyClass.
  * @param {Object} arg1 dependency object
  * @memberof MyClass
  */
 constructor(arg1) {
  this.var1 = arg1;
 }

 /**
  * My function
  *
  * @memberof MyClass
  */
 myFunction() {

 }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

I get eslint error

```
1:15  warning  Block must not be padded by blank lines  padded-blocks
```

And If I write like this

```js
class MyClass {
 /**
  * Creates an instance of MyClass.
  * @param {Object} arg1 dependency object
  * @memberof MyClass
  */
 constructor(arg1) {
  this.var1 = arg1;
 }

 /**
  * My function
  *
  * @memberof MyClass
  */
 myFunction() {

 }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

I get this error

```
2:2  warning  Expected line before comment  lines-around-comment
```

Seems like these rules are opposite to each other at starting of class.

How can I ignore `padded-blocks` rule for constructor named function case?

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading ESLint to the latest version. Issues related to the rules "lines-around-comment" and "padded-blocks" conflicting with each other should be settled by now. See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6526

In fact, in the current version 6.8.0, the first variant of your code [lints without warnings](https://eslint.org/demo#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).